# Blazor WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: Cannot allocate Wasm memory for new instance

Tags: android, blazor, runtime-error, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

In my Blazor app I sometimes get this while running the app on a tablet:

```
23:46:03.521 blazor.webassembly.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: Cannot allocate Wasm memory for new instance
await (async)
instantiateWasm @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
mc @ dotnet.7.0.2.bozgpca1o4.js:5
e.instantiateWasm @ dotnet.7.0.2.bozgpca1o4.js:5
createWasm @ dotnet.7.0.2.bozgpca1o4.js:14
(anonymous) @ dotnet.7.0.2.bozgpca1o4.js:14
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
await in (anonymous) (async)
start @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
Vt @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
await in Vt (async)
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
23:46:03.536 conflict-detection.min.js:5 waiting...
23:46:04.911 blazor.webassembly.js:1 RangeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Out of memory: Cannot allocate Wasm memory for new instance
u @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
await in u (async)
instantiateWasm @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
mc @ dotnet.7.0.2.bozgpca1o4.js:5
e.instantiateWasm @ dotnet.7.0.2.bozgpca1o4.js:5
createWasm @ dotnet.7.0.2.bozgpca1o4.js:14
(anonymous) @ dotnet.7.0.2.bozgpca1o4.js:14
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
await in (anonymous) (async)
start @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
Vt @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
await in Vt (async)
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
```

Any idea what I can do about this? Also seems like it sometimes throws this yellow error bar in the bottom and sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by setting below property in the .csproj file.

```
<EmccTotalMemory Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">134217728</EmccTotalMemory>
```

More info [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/53365)